# Texstudio - tooltips not showing up

Tags: texstudio, bugs, tooltips

I am running TeXstudio 4.6.3 on a Windows 11 machine with TexLive distribution.

I am getting crazy, I am not able to see any tooltips for any LaTeX commands. I have tried all the possible configuration options, even under "Advanced Options":

- "Show help as tooltip on text in editor" under "Adv. Editor" configuration tab is checked

[image: Adv. Editor picture]

- "Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-Commands" under "Completion" configuration tab is checked and is properly working, as well as "ToolTip-Help" and "ToolTip-Preview" under the same "Completion" configuration tab

[image: Completion tab picture]

The auto completer works properly (see picture below), but I can't see any help tooltips for any commands.

[image: Auto completer picture]

Is anybody experiencing the same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the user profile is corrupted. You can you look at the files stored here "c:\Documents and Settings/User/AppData/Roaming/texstudio".
You need to backup the folder first so that you will not lose your configurations. Then, delete the files. That will quintessentially reset the settings (configurations) to the default state. You see if that fixes it.

If that doesn't fix it, a complete removal of the app, including the folder mentioned above, using Rev-uninstaller or something similar might help.
If that doesn't help, you can try an earlier version because the version you are using could have bugs. (I cannot test because I am on the Mac).